# Throw exception of type 'E' with reflection in vb.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, exception, reflection

I would like to implement a method with the following logic:

```
mymethod(exceptionT as Type)
throw new exception of type exceptionT
```

In asp.net 4 (vb.net), I wrote this:

```
Public Shared Function raiseMyException(ByVal extype As Type) As Boolean
  Dim constructor = extype.GetConstructor(New Type() {Type.GetType("String")})
  Dim ex = constructor.Invoke(New String() {"Exception raised"})
 'Throw ex
```

But this fails: *throw should derive from System.exception*

How's possible to throw an exception of custom type with reflection?

Comment: Your custom type has to descend from Exception, otherwise throw is clueless. Somewhat puzzled by what you are trying to achieve here

Comment: All exceptions inherit from `Exception` so is there a specific reason why you use reflection? with your code, ANY type passed as a parameter can be used as you do not restrict what type you actually require.

Comment: Sorry if it make you puzzled. I'm working on a wrapper for some pretty old library. There are a bunch of methods that are virtually the same: call the original method, return true if it returned 1, or raise an exception if a description of the error is given. Therefore I would like to create a base-method that takes in input the name of the original method, the parameters required and the type of exception to be raised (if it's the case).

Comment: Sorry. I'm really tired at the moment. Ric's solution is the way to go.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could always try this, which uses generics:

```
Public Sub ThrowException(Of T As Exception)(message As String)
    Throw DirectCast(Activator.CreateInstance(GetType(T), message), T)
End Sub
```

Usage:

```
ThrowException(Of ArgumentException)("Error Message here")
```

You can replace `ArgumentException` with any exception deriving from `Exception`

But As @Steven Doggart mentions, isn't it easier just throwing an exception normally?

Comment: At that point, why use `Activator` at all?  You could just call `new T(message)` to instantiate the object.

Comment: Well the `new` must have the constraint specified in order to use `new`. This way, the `DirectCast` will alter the return type from `CreateInstance(..)` which is of type `object`, to `T` which is constrained to `Exception` and call the constructor for the exception. Thought this was worth mentioning. Another issue, using `new` as a constraint forces the use of the default parameterless constructor, if one exists.

Comment: As a matter of fact, the "New T("some text")" is invalid (the error I get is in Italian is something like "unable to use new with a parameter the has no "new" constraint)

Comment: I know, that's what I put in my comment. You would need this: `raiseMyException(Of T As {Exception, New})()...` but in doing this, you cannot pass a custom message of your choice and cannot set one. My answer allows you to do this.

Comment: Ah, I see.  I didn't have visual studio in front of me at the time, so I couldn't test it.  I just assumed that if you had the `Exception` constraint, it would allow you to create a new one without also specifying the `New` constraint, since, after all, `Exception` is instantiatable.  +1

Comment: if the new was apart of the constraints then New T() is possible but you can't add any arguments.

Comment: I'm deeply sorry @Ric. Your solution with Activator is what I'm using. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I suspect that your problem is that the type inference feature isn't working for you.  VB.NET will do it's best to infer the type for you, but if the type isn't clear, based on the context, then it can get the type wrong.  In this case, since you are using reflection to create the object, there's no way for the compiler to determine the type correctly at build-time.  I suspect that your `ex` variable is probably being typed as an `Object` rather than as an `Exception`.  You can fix it by specifying the type, like this:

```
Public Shared Function raiseMyException(ByVal extype As Type) As Boolean
    Dim constructor = extype.GetConstructor(New Type() {Type.GetType("String")})
    Dim ex As Exception = DirectCast(constructor.Invoke(New String() {"Exception raised"}), Exception)
    Throw ex
```

By the way, it's worth mentioning that, if it works in your situation, it would be even easier if you made it into a generic method, like this:

```
Public Shared Function raiseMyException(Of T As Exception)() As Boolean
    Throw New T("Exception Raised")
```

Of course, at that point, it's no easier than just throwing the exception directly rather than calling that method, but that's another discussion...

Comment: thanks for your hint about generic method. Anyway, as Ric pointed out, I cannot use "New T(mystring)". Activator fixes this.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Public Sub ThrowExceptionByType(exceptionType As Type)
    Dim ex As Exception = CType(exceptionType.Assembly.CreateInstance(exceptionType.FullName), Exception)
    Throw ex
End Sub
```

**Edit:**
This Obviously fails if the type is not an exception.... 
I think you will get an InvalidCastException instead of your custom exception :)
Maybe you want to check for that... but then you'll have problems if you do want to throw an InvalidCastException... You could check whether you individual type does inherit Exception... but what if it doesn't ... throw your own InvalidCastException? Or handle it by return codes? Well it's up to you.

Comment: Thanks for you help. I'd go with generic method as I don't want to handle a InvalidCastException.